# Window switching Mac OS way in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, desktop, alt-tab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an alternative to Exposé for Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/30491/is-there-an-alternative-to-expose-for-windows)

I love the way windows are auto arranged in Mac OS as the below screenshot.

Though, I'm a Windows OS user so I'm looking for way to have a similar feature on Windows 7. How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: You will find more suggestions in the answers to the following question: http://superuser.com/questions/30491/is-there-an-alternative-to-expose-for-windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of Expose style clones on Windows.

One of the more popular and very well written ones is Switcher.

http://insentient.net/

And a very helpful guide to use it:

http://blog.lib.umn.edu/ayubx003/dividebyzero/2009/01/05/expose_for_windows_vista_clone.html

Comment: Cool. I don't know why my google cannot come up with `Switcher`. Now with Start-` I can have it ^^

Comment: Yes, the guy who wrote Switcher, Bao Nguyen, hasn't updated it in a while and AFAIK is MIA.  But seeing how fast and bug free it runs is a testament to his skills as a developer. Unexpectedly, he wrote this in a **managed** language also (C#).

Comment: What is MIA? :)

Comment: It stands for **Missing in Action**. Informally, it means we have not heard from him in a long time and have no idea what or where he is now.